# Android image height in custom listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with custom rows. In imageView1 I set an image, but it is smaller than the height of the row . The image size is 4x30px. When I set a 40x300 img size (programmatically), the row gets too big (I know the reason: wrap_content). How can I set that the image be streched in height to the height of the row?

```
holder.image.setImageDrawable(convertView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.priority_4x30));
```

xml.file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:focusable="false" />

      <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:layout_width="180dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="15dip"
        android:paddingBottom="15dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1">
      </TextView>

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" />

      <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginRight="6sp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2">
      </CheckBox>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: maybe adding android:layout_alignParentTop="true" and android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to your ImageView would strech this. There is also a property for streching but I can't remember it's name now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make your relativelayout for each item have a static height

ex:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">
```

and then you can simply change your imageview to fill parent for its height

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this is good. Changing the RelativeLayout to LinearLayout also solves the problem.